# Preventing Directory Traversal in php get page script

Tags: php, directory-traversal, remote-file-inclusion, file-inclusion

I am trying to implement a secure php get page function afer my website got hacked with LFI, RFI and DTA (I got the whole package LOL).

Browsing the web I found this script which seems to work fine in preventing inclusions of files that I did not previously validated

```
<?$page = (!empty($_GET['page'])) ? $_GET['page'] : 'home.php';?>

<?// pick a page
switch ($page) {
case 'home.php': include($page); break;
case 'folder/page1.php': include($page); break;
case 'folder/folder/page2.php': include($page); break;
// don't accept any other values
default: /* error 404 for example */ unset($_GET['page'], $page); $a = false; break; 
}?>

<?if(!$a){
}?>

<?
if(!isset($page)) {
$a = true;
$page = 'home.php';
} ?>
```

Regarding Directory Traversal I found this OLD discussion here on Stackoverflow

[how to include a page in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11520634/how-to-include-a-page-in-php)

where Patrick Moore suggests to sanitize such scripts to prevent Directory Traversal with

```
$_GET['page'] = str_replace( array('..', '/', '\' ), '', $_GET['page'] );
```

However, I doubt I can use the script suggested by Patrick Moore, since several of the pages I have to include are contained in subfolders (see above example script), so I don't think I can sanitize the '/', and not sure how effective the script would be in preventing DTA's if I only str_replace `'..'` and `'\'`.

Any suggestion on how to sanitize the passed value given the folder structure of my website would be welcome.

Comment: is best to use a router. but the code you have shown because it has hardcoded defined checks on `$page` is safe from lfi

Comment: It is safe from LFI but not from Directory Traversal, which is the reason of my asking

Comment: sure it is, how would a string value `folder/folder/page2.php` be anything other than `folder/folder/page2.php`, are you not showing all the code?

Comment: If you are only allowing specific file names plus maybe specific folders via your switch construct already, then why would you need additional protection against path traversal? Anything containing `../` would not match any of the ”allowed” values in your switch cases anyway.